# SQL Server Config manager SQL service goes offline randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 CPT1 on my system. However, I'm encountering a recurring issue where the SQL Server service randomly goes offline, leading to login failures. I've noticed that restarting the service through SQL Server Configuration Manager temporarily resolves the problem. Could you please help me understand the possible reasons behind this service outage and suggest potential solutions to ensure stable and uninterrupted operation of the SQL Server service?

Comment: Wouldn't this question be more suitably posted on Superuser or Server Fault?

Comment: It's a CTP, meaning that it isn't ready for sale, and probably still has hundreds of bugs that MS wants to fix before release.  Aside from that, perhaps you could look in the SQL Server Logs - there could be something there.  Post it if you don't understand it.